# Unable to populate dropdown with mysql query

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I need to populate a dropdown with basic query but am unable to. I had previously populated it on accident but I needed to change something small and it snowballed out of control and I'm unable to produce a populated dropdown anymore.

```
<html>
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="view.php">Available Content</a></li>
        <li><a href="topic.php">Topics</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="sign_up.php">Sign-Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul> 


    <form method="post" action="topicChosen.php">
        <select name="selectitem">
            <?php
            require_once 'needed.php';
            if (isset($_SESSION["p_id"])) {
                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Select distinct topic from topic")) {
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($var1);
                    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                        echo "<option value=\"$var1\">$var1</option>";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //if user not logged in
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>




</html>
```

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0):

You don't check the return values of the MySQL calls. Add at least `or die($mysqli->error)` to see what's going wrong

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Select distinct topic from topic") or die($mysqli->error);
if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->bind_result($var1) or die($stmt->error);
    while ($stmt->fetch() or die($stmt->error)) {
        echo "<option value=\"$var1\">$var1</option>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on what to expect from die() but the query works fine and returns just the 1 column that I'm expecting, topic.

Comment: @GoodBoyNYC Then I misunderstood your question. I thought, you don't get the values for the `option` tags.

Comment: I've edited the original post with my results using phpMyAdmin. I'm unable to apply the values I get from my query to populate the dropdown menu.

Comment: @GoodBoyNYC If you don't get the values into the `option`s, then you need to debug the code and that could be done with the additional `die` statements.